# Login failed with Javax.mail via google

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I've been using the below code successfully from my laptop with recipients receiving the expected mail. However when putting the code in a jar and running from a hosted server. I get the below error.

***Code***

```
    Properties props = new Properties();  
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");  
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");  
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", 465);  
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", 465);  
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    Session mailSession = null;

    mailSession = Session.getInstance(props,  
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
            return new PasswordAuthentication("emailadress", "password");  
        }  
    }); 

    try {

        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

      message.setSubject("Todays Email!:");
      message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("theemailsender@gmail.com"));

      message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("recipient1@gmail.com"));

      String body = theBody;
      message.setContent(body,"text/html");
      transport.connect();

        transport.sendMessage(message,message.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
    } catch (Exception exception) {

    }
```

***Error***

```
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "35882577"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: STARTTLS requested but already using SSL
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN failed
```

I'm assuming at this point that I've either got to have either startle.enable or ssl.enable set to true but not both.

Comment: I've also experienced the same issues with sending from Gmail, sometimes it worked with one config for me on windows, and didn't for a colleague working on a Mac, or the other way around.

Comment: Thanks @chillworld. Either way they were arbitrary values. My real account details remain unpublished.

Comment: @TheMightyLlama Yeah but it seems a little to real(It was simpel but sometimes...) and there are some users who don't think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code works for me, if it can help. You can remove the part related to attachments.

```
public static void sendEmailWithAttachments(String host, String port, final String userName,
    final String password, String toAddress, String subject, String message,
    String[] attachFiles)
throws AddressException, MessagingException {
    // sets SMTP server properties
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.user", userName);
    properties.put("mail.password", password);

    // creates a new session with an authenticator
    Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
        }
    };
    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);

    // creates a new e-mail message
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));
    InternetAddress[] toAddresses = { new InternetAddress(toAddress) };
    msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setSentDate(new Date());

    // creates message part
    MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    messageBodyPart.setContent(message, "text/html");

    // creates multi-part
    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

    // adds attachments
    if (attachFiles != null && attachFiles.length > 0) {
        for (String filePath : attachFiles) {
            MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            try {
                attachPart.attachFile(filePath);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);
        }
    }

    // sets the multi-part as e-mail's content
    msg.setContent(multipart);

    // sends the e-mail
    Transport.send(msg);
}
```

In secure mode, you will probably have to replace port 465 by 587.

Answer (score 3):

follow the following your issue hopefully resolved

- First login into your gmail account then click on below path: 
  [google account](https://myaccount.google.com/security?pmr=1)

  in the security block, Just turned ON

  **Allow less secure apps: ON**

  Hope It will save your day..... Best of luck